# Existence of the integral $ \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{arctanh} (r)}{r}} \mathrm{d}r $

Tags: integration, trigonometry

For $-1 \le \alpha \le \beta \le 1$ i want to show that

$$ \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{arctanh} (r)}{r}} \mathrm{d}r $$

is finite. I know that for $\alpha = -1 $ and $ \beta = 1 $ this is true (thanks to wolfram alpha) and from that i could conclude it for arbitary $\alpha,\beta$ due to the positivity of the integrand. However I cannot prove above fact.

Comment: If $-1<\alpha < \beta <1$, then the integrand is continuous on $[\alpha,\beta]$ (with a suitable definition at $r=0$).

Comment: ok thanks but either way the case $\alpha = -1$ and $\beta = 1$ remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{\text{arctanh r}}{r}$ is an even function, so it is enough to show that
$$ \int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{\text{arctanh } r}{r}}\,dr $$
is finite for any $t\in[0,1]$. This can be done through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, since
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{arctanh }r}{r}\,dr = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$
ensures:
$$ \int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{\text{arctanh } r}{r}}\,dr \leq\sqrt{\int_{0}^{t}1\,dr\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\text{arctanh } r}{r}\,dr}\leq \pi\sqrt{\frac{t}{8}}.$$
We  may also state $ \int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{\text{arctanh } r}{r}}\,dr \leq\frac{\pi t}{2\sqrt{2}}$ by exploiting convexity, but the above (quite crude) inequality is already enough to prove that $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sqrt{\frac{\text{arctanh } r}{r}}\,dr $ is finite for any $\alpha,\beta\in[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\tanh(t)$ is a concave function, we know that $\tanh(t)\ge t\tanh(1)$ on $[0,1]$. Furthermore, $\tanh(t)\ge\tanh(1)$ for $t\ge1$. Thus,
$$\newcommand{\arctanh}{\operatorname{arctanh}}\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{\frac{\arctanh(r)}{r}}\,\mathrm{d}r
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sqrt{\frac{t}{\tanh(t)}}\,\mathrm{d}\tanh(t)\\
&=2\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\frac{t}{\tanh(t)}}\sech^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\le2\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac1{\tanh(1)}}\,\mathrm{d}t+\int_1^\infty\sqrt{\frac{t}{\tanh(1)}}4e^{-2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\le\frac1{\sqrt{\tanh(1)}}\left(2+\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for all $\alpha\le\beta$, we have
$$
\int_\alpha^\beta\sqrt{\frac{\arctanh(r)}{r}}\,\mathrm{d}r\le\frac1{\sqrt{\tanh(1)}}\left(2+\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\right)
$$